# Is it possible to get a Blaze to spawn on a Skyblock map?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been playing the Skyblock 2.1 map for Minecraft and have figured out there's a way to get Villagers, but only if you can first get a Blaze Rod. In Skyblock, the Nether consists of only a small 3x3x3 block of glowstone and a portal within the boundaries of the Skyblock map, nothing else. I presume if one went far enough in any direction they would find normal chunks (and thus the possibility of Nether fortresses and Blaze spawners), but this would be cheating.

After perusing [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/90363/15), it's clear that even when all the blocks of a Nether fortress are removed you can still get Blazes (and Withers) to spawn in that location if you just build some new ground there. So, if the valid playable region of a Skyblock map originally contained a Nether fortress, and if the data for the ["Structure Pieces"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/107229/15) of that Nether fortress still remain in the folder for the Skyblock map, it should be possible to get a Blaze to spawn.

So, the million-emerald question...

**Has anyone either found a location where Blazes spawned, or used some method/mod to determine if there are any Blaze-spawnable regions in the valid playable section of the Nether of a Skyblock map?**

Comment: Million Emerald question. :) Love it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Bounding Box Outline](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1538820-bounding-box-outline/) mod will show you nicely-shaded bounding boxes for all Structure Pieces placed in the world, including Nether Fortresses. It's currently available for 1.6.x and requires [Minecraft Forge](http://www.minecraftforge.net/wiki/Installation/Universal).

I've already got a Forge profile laying around, so it was a simple matter of dropping the mod in a fresh game directory along with the Skyblock 2.1 save, an edit to the `level.dat` to enable Creative, and lo and behold:

[image: Nether Fortress outlines are visible near the Nether portal]

So yes, there are *two* Nether Fortress "ghosts" not far from the glowstone island.

The nearest corner of the one visible on the left is at approximately 76, 62, -63 (XYZ) and stretches to the North and a bit to the East from there, not including a hallway protruding to the West (the direction back toward the portal, but farther North than this corner).

The nearest corner of the one visible on the right is at approximately 94, 71, 73 and stretches East from there with a Southward and downward tendency.

You could go off those numbers and just grope around trying to make a blaze-spawnable area without the mod. If you want to use the mod though, it's quite easy to install starting from zero modding experience: download and use the automatic Forge installer which will create a new forge-enabled Profile, then drop the Bounding Box Outline mod's zipfile into the new `.minecraft/mods/` folder that will be created after you run Forge once. Once in the game, turn the mod's visuals on by pressing <kbd>F3</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> (simultaneously) and the fortresses will show up bright as day.

Comment: So, I guess I'd have to install the mod then fly around on creative all over the Skyblock Nether. How big is the empty part of the Skyblock Nether anyway?

Comment: @gnovice Hold on, I got a screenshot incoming!

Comment: Hot damn! They're *right there* near the portal. I thought it would be a huge ordeal to search around for them. I am in your debt, good sir. Testificate sky village, here I come!

Comment: @gnovice Enjoy! (Aside, I'm very curious how blaze rods can be turned into villagers. ... Oh, scratch that! The cured zombie method! Right. That's enough work that you'll definitely have earned it.)

Comment: This is great.  Any chance someone has a way of testing on 1.16 snapshot?  The coordinates didn't work for me with the new nether update.

Comment: @tresf I started playing a 1.15.2 skyblock recently and checked it with the [Bounding Box Outline Reloaded mod](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/bounding-box-outline-reloaded). The closest Nether fortress I found was around X = 0, Z = 611. Building a platform further in Z should spawn Blazes. However, this does put you in view of the map edge. Not sure if the coordinates are the same for a 1.16 snapshot.

Answer (score 2):

If the purpose of this is to get a villager, it's unnecessary. All you need to do is get a zombie villager, a witch, and trap both of them, and make the witch continuously pelt the zombie with potions, until throws a weakness potion. From then on, you can kill the witch or block it off and proceed to cure the zombie villager.
This video kind of explains how you do it, just skip the irrelevant parts.

Comment: I finally trapped the zombie villager and the witch (took a while and a lot of deaths).  How do I know which potion was "weakness", simply by being in range and being hit too?  The blaze rod solution seems like there are much less variables at play, since -- when crafting your own -- there's not an angry witch throwing poison mid-heal.

Comment: @tresf You have to be within 3 blocks or so of the witch to get a chance of her using a weakness potion, but she will also use potions of harming that close as well. Too far away and she only throws poison and slowness.

Comment: Thanks.  I took a very long time but I eventually got it.

Answer (score -6):

Well, you could do that, but that's not how it's supposed to be done in Skyblock. If you follow the HQM quests it will show you how to do it. First you craft a stone barrel and fill it with lava. Then you make an angry doll (you need to get some of the materials using other mods like Mariculture), and right click with it on the barrel to spawn a blaze.

Comment: Not all skyblocks are HQM. In this case, this is a vanilla skyblock without any mods at all.